# How to read and overwrite text file simultaneously in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to filter out duplicate lines in a text. I used `ruby -i` to edit in-place, but the result only outputs to `stdout`. So I tried to write by hand.

```
ARGV.each do |filename|
    File.open(filename, 'r+') do |file|
        ret = file.readlines.uniq.join()
        # file.rewind
        # file.truncate(???)
        # file.seek(0)
        # file.write ret
        file.puts ret
    end
end
```

None of them works. The best I can get is the content appended to the file, which merely makes more duplicates.

Please show some mercy to me.

Comment: What are all those empty regexes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use -i to edit in-place".

Comment: @sawa ruby interpreter option, these are not regex, these are commented out code that I tried that did not work.

Comment: In Ruby, `//` does not work as comment.

Comment: @sawa  Sorry, I forgot, but the code did not use //, they use #

Comment: Then correct it.

Comment: @sawa, You did not say please. But it is my mistake, so I will do it.

Comment: Your goal is to remove duplicates from file. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
ARGV.each do |filename|
  new_content = File.readlines(filename).uniq(&:rstrip).join.rstrip
  File.write(filename, new_content)
end
```

This reads the entire file as individual lines, removes duplicate lines (ignoring the new line character(s)), concatenates the lines to create new file's content as one string and removes white spaces from its end. Finally we write new content to the file overriding existing content.

Note that the new version of the file won't have new line character at the end. If you want new line character at the end of the file you can just append it to `new_content` before the `File::write` call.

---

If you want to use the same handle for reading and writing, then do something like this:

```rb
ARGV.each do |filename|
  File.open(filename, 'r+') do |f|
    new_content = f.readlines.uniq(&:rstrip).join.rstrip  # Read the entire file as individual lines, removes duplicate lines (ignoring the new line character(s)), concatenate the lines to create new file's content as one string and remove white spaces from its end
    f.rewind                                              # Rewind to the beginning of the file
    f.write(new_content)                                  # Write new content to the file overriding existing content
    f.truncate(f.pos)                                     # Remove the file's content after the current position
  end
end
```

Although I can't see any real advantage of this version vs the first. The code becomes more messy, and we are forced to use [`File#truncate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/File.html#method-i-truncate) which is described as "Not available on all platforms.".

Comment: **WARNING**: Careful when using in-place modifiers like `uniq!` when you don't have the original in a variable. If no duplicates are found `uniq!` will return `nil`. By comparison, `uniq` *always* returns a copy of the array with the duplicates removed and is the appropriate tool here.

Comment: @tadman Thanks - I wasn't aware of that. In that case I have to agree that `uniq` is a better choice here.

Comment: Though I was trying to use the same handle, but forget it, this is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read the file line by line and push into array and make it uniq. Then print the lines

```
ARGV.each do |filename|      
  text=File.open(filename).read
  text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
  lines=[]
  text.each_line do |line|
    lines << line unless lines.include? line
  end
  File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
    f.puts(lines)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the regex for line-ending should be \r?\n, and why not just use readlines to read as an array directly? And I just want to open the file once.

Comment: Then open file in read and write mode like w+. then write the logic inside.

Comment: w+ would truncate the file, how do we manipulate the contents?

Comment: Note: `File.readlines` would be a lot less messy. You can even filter that through `grep` to get the lines you want.